# What is the fastest way to empty s3 bucket using boto3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, boto3

I was thinking about deleting and then re-creating bucket (bad option which I realised later).

Then how can delete all objects from the bucket?

I tried this : http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.delete_objects

But it deletes multiple objects not all.

can you suggest what is the best way to empty bucket ?

Comment: This is a limitation of the S3 API - [delete multiple object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/multiobjectdeleteapi.html). You will have to implement pagination and delete 1000 at a time.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the [Amazon Web Services CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html).

```
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket --recursive
```

For a longer answer, if you insists to use boto3, this will send a delete marker to s3, with no folder handling required. `bucket.Object.all` will create a iterator that not limit to 1K:

```
import boto3    
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
# suggested by Jordon Philips 
bucket.objects.all().delete()
```

Comment: You can also just do `bucket.objects.all().delete()`, though it gets a bit more complicated if your bucket is versioned

Comment: @JordonPhillips Thank for your answer. This worked for me as I'm not using versioning for my bucket. But will this find all the objects inside the bucket and then delete them one by one? what happens when there are huge amounts of data in bucket ? Will it be slow?

Comment: @TusharNiras :  whether object store or normal file system, `delete` is just about removing the index.

Comment: @TusharNiras, Under the hood boto3 will use [`delete_objects`](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_objects) when you use that snippet, so you will make one request per page of objects (up to 1000 at a time). This is as fast as you can make it without threading.

Comment: If you don't have the DeleteObject permission, the objects will not be deleted and an error will NOT be raised. After I added the permission the objects were deleted as expected.

Comment: This literally does nothing for me. It returns without error, but the bucket I specify continues to exist.

Comment: @Cerin : Can you check your bucket policy and your user rights?

Comment: Looks like you can now skip the `.all()` and just do `bucket.objects.delete()`. https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket.objects.

Answer (score 26):

If versioning is enabled, there's a similar call to the other answer to delete all object versions:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
bucket.object_versions.delete()
```

Comment: i found this to be incredibly slow. It seems to collect and return details about each object when complete, maybe this is why? any hints there? (I know the question asked specifically for boto3, but the console "empty" option is much faster)

Answer (score 17):

Based on previous responses, and adding check of versioning enabled, you can empty a bucket, with versions enabled or not doing:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
bucket_versioning = s3.BucketVersioning(bucket_name)
if bucket_versioning.status == 'Enabled':
    s3_bucket.object_versions.delete()
else:
    s3_bucket.objects.all().delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you need to use low-level operations on `boto3` and yoy need to use `boto3.client` instead of `boto3.resource` here's a code that can help. In which I called all the objects with `s3_client.list_objects_v2` and extracted the key on them in order to delete them with `s3_client.delete_objects`

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
objects = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket = "bucket-name")["Contents"]
objects = list(map(lambda x: {"Key":x["Key"]},objects))
s3_client.delete_objects(Bucket = "bucket-name", Delete = {"Objects":objects})
```

Comment: be aware this piece of code does not have pagination

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm using

```py
def filter_list_of_dicts_key_startswith(list_of_dicts: list, key: str, value: str) -> list:
    return [item for item in list_of_dicts if item[key].startswith(value)]

def delete_s3_bucket(session: any, region: str, bucket_name: str) -> None:
    client = session.client("s3", region_name=region)
    client.delete_bucket(Bucket=bucket_name)
    print(f"       -> ️  S3 Bucket Deleted: {bucket_name}")


def delete_s3_bucket_objects(session: any, region: str, bucket_name: str) -> None:
    client = session.client("s3", region_name=region)
    objects = client.get_paginator("list_objects_v2")

    objects_iterator = objects.paginate(Bucket=bucket_name)
    for page in objects_iterator:
        if "Contents" in page:
            objects = [{"Key": obj["Key"]} for obj in page["Contents"]]
            client.delete_objects(Bucket=bucket_name, Delete={"Objects": objects})
            print(f"       -> ️  S3 Bucket Objects Deleted: {len(objects)}")



...

session = boto3.Session(profile_name="my-profile-account")
client = session.client("s3", region_name="us-east-1")
list_buckets = client.list_buckets()
buckets = list_buckets["Buckets"]

print(f"     S3 Available Buckets: {len(buckets)}")
for bucket in buckets:
    print(f"      -> {bucket['Name']}, Creation Date = {bucket['CreationDate']}")

buckets_filtered = filter_list_of_dicts_key_startswith(buckets, "Name", "this-is-a-test-bucket-prefix-")

print(f"    ⛔ S3 Buckets to Delete: {len(buckets_filtered)}")
for bucket in buckets_filtered:
    print(f"      -> {bucket['Name']}, Creation Date = {bucket['CreationDate']}")

    delete_s3_bucket_objects(session, "us-east-1", bucket["Name"])
    delete_s3_bucket(session, "us-east-1", bucket["Name"])
...
```

Answer (score -3):

I wrote a function to do that.

```
class AWS_Helper:

    def __init__(self):
        self.s3_client= None
        self.region_name = <region name>
        session  = boto3.Session()
        self.s3_client = session.resource('s3')
        print("Connected")

    def create_bucket(self, bucketname):
        print("Creating Bucket:"+bucketname)
        self.s3_client.create_bucket(Bucket=bucketname,CreateBucketConfiguration={
                              'LocationConstraint': self.region_name})
        print("Created")

    def get_all_buckets(self):
        return self.s3_client.buckets.all()

    def get_all_bucket_objects(self):
        my_bucket = self.s3_client.Bucket(self.bucketname)
        res = []
        # for s3_file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        for s3_file in sorted(my_bucket.objects.all(), key=obj_last_modified, reverse=True):
            res.append({"key":s3_file.key,"date":s3_file.last_modified,"size":s3_file.size})
        return res

    def check_bucket_exists(self, bucketname):
        return self.s3_client.Bucket(bucketname) in self.get_all_buckets()

    def put_file_to_bucket(self, filepath,filename):
        #data = open(filepath, 'rb')
        self.s3_client.Bucket(self.bucketname).upload_file(filepath, filename)

    def delete_file(self,object_name):
        try:
            obj = self.s3_client.Object(self.bucketname, object_name)
            obj.delete()
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(str(e))
        return True
```