# Delete all versions of a particular file format inside a folder in an Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm using a good example to delete all file versions, delete markers and objects inside an Amazon S3 bucket and folder https://stackoverflow.com/a/53872419/387774

```
import boto3
bucket = "my-bucket-name"
filename = "my-folder/filename.xml"
client = boto3.client("s3")
paginator = client.get_paginator("list_object_versions")
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)
for response in response_iterator:
    versions = response.get("Versions", [])
    versions.extend(response.get("DeleteMarkers", []))
    for version_id in [
        x["VersionId"]
        for x in versions
        if x["Key"] == filename and x["VersionId"] != "null"
    ]:
        print("Deleting {} version {}".format(filename, version_id))
        client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=filename, VersionId=version_id)
```

The problem I'm facing is there are thousands of files and their versions. I do not know the names of all those files. I would like to delete all of them using some wildcard like `filename = "my-folder/*.xml"`

What changes can I make?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326493/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-empty-s3-bucket-using-boto3

Comment: Are you saying that Versioning is enabled on the bucket, and some objects that you wish to delete have multiple versions -- all of which you wish to remove? How many objects are in the bucket? Is this a one-off activity, or a continuing activity? I'm asking to figure out whether obtaining an [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html) listing would be helpful.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - Yes, there are multiple versions of the same file that I would like to remove. There are many objects possibly close to 50k files.
This is one off activity.

Comment: Is your goal to completely empty the bucket or everything, or do you you simply wish to delete the non-current version of objects?

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68986110/python-script-to-delete-all-versions-including-delete-marker-in-s3-for-files-wit).

Comment: Unfortunately boto3 is not able to filter via suffix. 
I think you can use prefix to get all the filenames in that dir via list_objects_v2. And then keep the names of the files that ends with your extension. Then you can delete those objects.