# python script to delete all versions including delete marker in S3 for files with certain prefix

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I used a aws cli script to delete all files starting with certain prefix.

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket/folder/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "file_prefix*"
```

This worked but since I have the versioning enabled on the bucket it puts a delete marker on all files.

I would like a python script to delete all versions including the delete marker. This is what I created, but this is not working on the prefix.

```
import boto3

bucket = "my-bucket"
filename = "folder/file_prefix*"

client = boto3.client("s3")
paginator = client.get_paginator("list_object_versions")
response_iterator = paginator.paginate(Bucket=bucket)
for response in response_iterator:
   versions = response.get("Versions", [])
   versions.extend(response.get("DeleteMarkers", []))
   for version_id in [
       x["VersionId"]
       for x in versions
       if x["Key"] == filename and x["VersionId"] != "null"
   ]:
       print("Deleting {} version {}".format(filename, version_id))
       client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=filename, VersionId=version_id)
```

Comment: If you are concerned that this script might do the wrong thing, you should test it against a representative S3 bucket and also backup the current bucket's content. Code reviews are generally out of scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jarmod - I tried this and the script is not working, I edited my question.

Comment: I wouldn't expect `x["Key"] == filename` to work given that `filename = "folder/file_prefix*"`.

Comment: "script is not working," is not specific. What exactly is happening? Any errors? how anyone can take your code and reproduce the issue?