# fast way to empty the s3 bucket using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am using the below boto3 code (source [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326493/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-empty-s3-bucket-using-boto3)) to empty the bucket, but it takes a huge time since the bucket has large numbers of versioned objects to delete.

```py
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
bucket.object_versions.delete()
```

The above code is working but it is taking nearly a day to empty it.

Is there a way to empty it faster?

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this synchronously -- you need to know that the bucket is empty when your program is done -- then the only way to speed it up is to spread the work between multiple threads/processes. I would have one main thread that gets a listing of objects and then uses the `concurrent.futures` package to dispatch a delete on each object in the list.

Be aware that you are [charged for all operations invoked from a client program](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/).

If you can do the deletes asynchronously -- over the course of a couple of days -- then the best solution is [a lifecycle rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-expire-general-considerations.html). This happens entirely within S3, and you don't get charged for the individual deletes.

Comment: Lifecycle events! Great idea.

Comment: Agreed. Please note that a Lifecycle Rule will not delete the objects immediately -- it might take 24 hours to activate.